# Writing an Excel VBA to assign numbers to different combinations

Tags: vba, excel, combinations

I have been looking to create combinations and line them up vertically. I need help for assigning numbers to the given combinations. As an example, I am looking to make combinations of `A,B,C,D,E`. I have gotten to

```
A

A
B

A
B
C
.
.
.
```

What I would like now is to assign numbers like

```
1A

2A
2B

3A
3B
3C
. 
.
.
```

I feel like, I can add to the code I have to do the transpose, which is

```
Sub TransposeSpecial()
Dim lMaxRows As Long 'max rows in the sheet
Dim lThisRow As Long 'row being processed
Dim lThisRow2 As Long 'row being processed
Dim iMaxCol As Integer 'max used column in the row being processed

    lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets.Add Type:=xlWorksheet, Count:=1, after:=Sheets(1)
    lThisRow = 1 'start from row 1
    lThisRow2 = 1 'start from row 1
    Do While lThisRow < lMaxRows
        Sheets(1).Activate
        iMaxCol = Cells(lThisRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        If (iMaxCol > 1) Then            
            Range(Cells(lThisRow, 2), Cells(lThisRow, iMaxCol)).Copy

            Sheets(2).Activate
            Range("B" & lThisRow2 + 1).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, transpose:=True
            lThisRow2 = lThisRow2 + iMaxCol
        End If

        lThisRow = lThisRow + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `1A`? it is `Count of non-empty cells of the part & A` or `Number of the part & A` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it also without VBA code:
(You original data are in `A`)

- If you want *Number of block & Value*, You can have your values in another column:

```
=IF(A1 = ""; ""; CONCATENATE(COUNTBLANK(INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROW())) + 1; A1))
```

Now you can *Copy* and *Paste* results as where as you want, And don't forgot you can *Paste values only*.

Comment: That isn't working. I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do. I just want to put the number of the combination next to all parts of the combination. I cannot just continually copy and paste because I have over 8,000 combinations.

Comment: @Sam As I see in your sample output you have one column and you want to add a number before the value of that column, Am I in right way?

Comment: Yes, I have the column added, and I have been able to get it to print the correct number in the first cell in each combination.for example:
1A
  B
  C

2B
  C

3A
  C
but what I want is for the number to be pasted in front of all letters in the combinations

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Assign_Numbers()
    Dim lngLastRow As Long, intCounter As Integer, x As Long

    lngLastRow = Range("A1").Offset(Rows.Count - 1).End(xlUp).Row
    intCounter = 1

    For x = 2 To lngLastRow
        If Cells(x, 1).Value <> "" Then
            Cells(x, 1).Value = intCounter & Cells(x, 1).Value
        Else
            intCounter = intCounter + 1
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```